# linear inequalities in semi-definite program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

A standard form of SDP is 
$\min_x c^Tx$ s.t. $F(x)\succcurlyeq 0$ 
where $F(x)=F_0+\sum_{i=1}^m F_m$ and $F_0,F_1,...,F_m$ are symmetric matrices and $\succcurlyeq 0$ indicates that the matrix is positive semidefinite. 
It is stated in many notes (such as [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee227a/fa10/login/l_conic_sdp.html](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee227a/fa10/login/l_conic_sdp.html) under the section special cases) that a linear inequality (where inequality corresponding to a vector denotes component-wise inequality) can be re-formulated as an SDP inequality by defining a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements as the components of the vector.
My doubt is suppose in a problem, we have a large number of component-wise inequalities and we reformulate it as an SDP problem, is it even computationally feasible (assuming the constraint also has an SDP inequality, thus, there is a dire need for SDP formulation). I am asking this because in such a scenario we are faced with a large number of sparse matrices and the algorithm may take a lot of memory and time to solve. Or is there any better way to deal with such situations?

Comment: Take a look at the SOCP formulation of the convex problem. SOCP exploits the sparsity in the constraint set. Most of the commercial solvers are equipped with SOCP solvers. Can take a look at  https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/lecture6.pdf to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an actual solver you don't formulate linear inequalities using a diagonal matrix which you work with in the SDP cone, but you work with the elementwise (and socp) cone explicitly. The fact that you could do it using a diagonal matrix is just a way to convince the reader that elementwise constraints are easily dealt with both in theory and practice.